# Roll up/group by two rows of data with 2 different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I hope the title is somewhat explanatory, but let's assume I have data that looks like this:

```
     Num1          Val1           Type             Code           String1          String 2
     1X2           GG             X11              123            NULL             NULL
     1X2           GG             X11              123            Test String      Test String
```

What I am hoping to achieve is something like that:

```
  Num1          Val1           Type             Code           String1          String 2
  1X2           GG             X11              123            Test String      Test String
```

I tried something like :

```
  Select Num1, Val1, Type, Code, MAX(String1) as String1, and MAX(String2) as String2
  From table
  Group Num1, Val1, Type, Code
```

I'm just testing it out with MAX because I don't know if something like that is even doable with STRING, I use that with numeric values, but is there any way to combine two rows as shown above?

Comment: Your code should work.

Comment: You have an extra `AND` in there and no `BY` in your GROUP statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extra AND
2. GROUP BY (Not GROUP)

```
  Select Num1, Val1, Type, Code, MAX(String1) as String1, MAX(String2) as String2
  From table
  Group BY Num1, Val1, Type, Code
```

Your code will work for the situation shown. However, if you had the following it would also give you the same answer:

```
 Num1          Val1           Type             Code           String1          String 2
     1X2           GG             X11              123         NULL            Test String
     1X2           GG             X11              123         Test String     NULL
```

Depending on your exact requirements, an [UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement may also be an option.